# Push android notifications using parse, NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, crash, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to push android notifications using Parse, but the app crashes.

Here's my code for
`ParseApplication.java`:

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, "t9FCgoS4236bMVSZiXUWyzjX4pHMIThqRQA75Msh", "xNPNRx9su5iiAK8owJoozEK0Ft2cZenanCJ06Y3V");
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
```

ParseReceiver.java

```
public class ParseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

private final String TAG = "Parse Notification";
private String msg = "";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Log.i(TAG, "PUSH RECEIVED!!!");

    try {
        String action = arg1.getAction();
        String channel = arg1.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
        JSONObject json = new   J  JSONObject(arg1.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

        Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");
        Iterator itr = json.keys();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) itr.next();
            Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
            if(key.equals("string")){
                msg = json.getString(key);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
    }


    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(arg0.getResources(),
            R.drawable.happy);

    Intent launchActivity = new Intent(arg0, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0, launchActivity, 0);

    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(arg0)
    .setContentTitle("PUSH RECEIVED")
    .setContentText(msg)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.happy)
    .setLargeIcon(icon)
    .setContentIntent(pi)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build();

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)arg0.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(0, noti);
}
```

}

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.parse"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name="com.example.parse.ParseApplication" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.parse.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".ParseReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action      android:name="com.makemyandroidapp.parsenotificationexample.RECEIVE_PUSH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

And my logcat:

```
    04-25 09:53:49.754: I/dalvikvm(370): Could not find   method  com.parse.Parse.initialize, referenced from method c      com.example.parse.ParseApplication.onCreate
04-25 09:53:49.784: W/dalvikvm(370): VFY: unable to resolve static method   43: Lcom/parse/Parse;.initialize    (Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
 04-25 09:53:49.784: D/dalvikvm(370): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0007
 04-25 09:53:49.804: D/AndroidRuntime(370): Shutting down VM
 04-25 09:53:49.804: W/dalvikvm(370): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught        exception (group=0x40014760)
 04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.Parse  
04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at com.example.parse.ParseApplication.onCreate(ParseApplication.java:16)
04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:968)
04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3580)
04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1031)
04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-25 09:53:49.905: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 09:53:57.356: I/Process(370): Sending signal. PID: 370 SIG: 9
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: are you added the parse lib to the project?

Comment: yeahh...I have added parse.jar to my library..

Comment: Please show line 16 in ParseApplication.

Comment: Parse.initialize(this, "t9FCgoS4236bMVSZiXUWyzjX4pHMIThqRQA75Msh", "xNPNRx9su5iiAK8owJoozEK0Ft2cZenanCJ06Y3V");
  PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);

Comment: Here the setDefaultPushcallback from type Pushservice is depreciated....it showss.....warning...

Comment: See this [link](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/app-crash-on-push-test).. This may helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Check your dependencies and be sure you're compiling Parse with your project.

Comment: check your module dependencies - it should be set to compile, aswell check your gradle include files.

Comment: @SaiKumar no you did not include it properly, that's why the error says "NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.Parse"